# How to get a missing string sequence in PHP Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

we have warehouse LOCATIONS in a system like this.

D2705B, D2805C, F3805C, F3805F

So we used these all locations but want to know which locations are not used YET.

Case 1: D2705B USED means missing D2705A (Need to go back so ending with A is the missing location)

Case 1:D2805C USED means missing D2805B, D2805A (Need to go back so ending with A and B is the missing location)

Case 3: F3805C, F3805F First 4 digits same so C and F are used but B, A and D is missing

Basic Requirments are: For example, we have a stock location in system D2705A, D2705E, but if no product is using D2705B, C, D, then the system should show missing location D2705B, C, D;

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your question, you need to generate all missing "locations" based on the last letter from the number. So if you have:
`F3805F`, you need to get `F3805A`, `F3805B`, `F3805C`, `F3805D`, `F3805E`.

```php
$location = 'F3805F'; // last location 
$base = substr($location, 0, 5); // gives 'F3805'
$lastLetter = substr($location, -1); // gives 'F'

$missingLocations = [];

foreach (range('A', $lastLetter)as $letter) {
  if ($letter === $lastLetter) {
    break;
  }
  $missingLocations[] = $base.$letter;
}

print_r($missingLocations);
```

That gives you an array of missing locations:

> Array
> (
> [0] => F3805A
> [1] => F3805B
> [2] => F3805C
> [3] => F3805D
> [4] => F3805E
> )

You can now diff this array with existing locations.

Comment: yes #daniel Thank you very much for your answer.

Yes, it works in one case when we only have 1 location with a BASE location, so works fine.

BUT we have another case i.e we have  'F3805D' and 'F3805G' USED and found in the system,
BUT we never used: F3805A, F3805B, F3805DC and F3805E, F3805F

So should also need this.

BUT i got an idea of how to get it, i am checking it if it helps i will mark as accepted.

Comment: The idea is we have already made locations in warehouse  XYZ09A to XYZ09Z

So if the user has to check it takes a lot of time to check which locations we are missing to put products on that so the system tries to find all between this

The idea is to only check the last A-Z only if only 1 is used then need to get the location before that Alphabet i.e if Z is used then it means before Z all are empty so if two used B-E, it means A,c,d is missing

Answer (score 0):

```
$locations = ['A' , 'C']; #it will return me B
$locations = ['M']; #it will return me A to N

 if ($locations) {

    $first = strtoupper(current($locations));
    $last = strtoupper(end($locations));

    if (count($locations) == 1)
       $first = 'A';

        foreach (range($first, $last) as $letter) {
         if ($letter === $last) {
            break;
         }
         if (in_array($letter, $locations)) continue;
             $foundMissingLocations[] = $loc->stock_location_4 . $letter;
         }

   print_r($foundMissingLocations);
 }
```

Comment: but thank you very much @Daniel for your TIP.